# Как сделать чтоб gulp автоматический перезагружался?

Tags: gulp

Как сделать так, чтобы Gulp автоматом перезагружался?

Просто когда создаю переменную в файле *less.index*, он останавливается и пишет:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [2] variable @newVar is undefined in file
>   C:\Users\Борис\WebstormProjects\less\src\less\index.less line no. 4

Но после его перезагрузки все работает нормально.

Comment: Нужно ловить ошибки, вызванные модулем и их обрабатывать. Нужен код `gulpfile.js`

Comment: gulpfile.js все есть и подключено просто когда в less пишу переменную думаю об ее названии и начинаю ее писать происходит ошибка и галп прекращает свою работу приходиться опять его запускать в терминале gulp

Comment: Понятна проблема, но без содержимого галпфайла сложно помочь